# V-if para verificar se checkbox está checado

Tags: vue.js

Como eu faço para fazer um `v-if` Se o `v-checkbox` estiver checado?

Tentei `v-if(nomedoV-model == true)` e não deu certo.

Comment: v-if="nomedoVmodel"

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo simples, temos o checkbox associado à um objeto chamado checked

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="checked">
<label for="checkbox">Você é maior de 18 anos?</label>
<h1 v-if="checked"> Você pode tirar a habilitação! </h1>
<h1 v-if="!checked"> Você não pode tirar a habilitação! </h1>
```

e no data:

```
data() {
 return {
  checked: false,
 }
}
```

como o valor de checked está inicialmente como false, o checkbox ficará desmarcado e o texto que irá aparecer é o "Você não pode tirar a habilitação" pois o v-if esta com '!checked', o ! impõe que se o checked for o inverso de true, ou seja false, a condição é verdadeira e irá executar tal ação, que no caso é mostrar esse texto.